# where can i find Qt graphs or how to build them

Tags: qt, graph

hello im looking for Qt graph widgets that are free 
something like [qwt.sourceforge.net/](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/index.html)

Comment: no good pie chart , but i gut idea to use the qwebkit + js charts 
there are many of them...

Answer (score 1):

Outside of Qt, there's also MathGL, which is a powerful graphing library as well. It can create images (png, jpg, svg etc...) which can easily be displayd in a Qt widget. You'll of course have to sacrifice the interactivity that Qwt can offer.